# Inferring $R^2$ from scatterplot visualization

Tags: r-squared, scatterplot

I have two dataframes (modelled and observed) each representing values of mean NPP for the years 2000,2001,2002....till  2010

```
observed<-c(0.68,0.67,0.70,0.68,0.67,0.69,0.72,0.70,0.70,0.70,0.70)
modelled<-c(0.73,0.76,0.74,0.75,0.71,0.77,0.76,0.76,0.78,0.78,0.79)
```

I plot a scatterplot by using the following code

```
 df = data.frame(modelled,observed)
    plot(x = df$modelled,y = df$observed)
```

and I compute the r2 through

```
    summary(lm(modelled~observed, data=df))$r.squared 
summary(lm(modelled~observed, data=df))$r.squared
```

r2 value is 0.28
The scatterplot can been seen below:

[image: scatterplot]

What can be inferred from this scatterplot? How come by r2 is coming so low even if the means for both modelled and observed are coming very close to each other?
Background Information: The observed values represent mean NPP (from MODIS satellite) for the years 2000,2001,2002..till 2010. The modelled values represent mean NPP values for 2000,2001,2002..till 2010.

Comment: but the paired data points, hollow dots, are showing that the two data series are not very alike, regardless of their mean. If they were alike, you would see a 45 degree line of hollow dots for your scatter plot. So the low $R^2$ seems justified

Comment: even if observed means are exactly the same as modeled ones, R2 may be low, if residual variance is high compared to model variance